# "Вот(,) что..."

Tags: пунктуация

У меня слабым местом является оборот "вот(,) что..." Подскажите, пожалуйста, когда тут нужна запятая, а когда нет? Например: "Вот(,) что я хочу сказать". Или "Вот(,) что. Я решил сводить тебя в зоопарк". Или "Я придумал вот(,) что".
Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

"ВОТ" в большинстве случаев является указательной частицей, она тесно связана с тем словом, к которому относится, и не отделяется от него запятой. В том числе ВОТ может относиться к местоименным словам: вот что, вот чем, вот как и др.